# Cell Value given row and column numbers

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to get a cell value in Access table given row number and column number. Does anyone know how is it possible to do this?

Comment: MS Access does not have row numbers and column numbers. It uses a database, not a spreadsheet.

Comment: It is 'possible' if you are using a form in datasheet view. However, as indicated by Fionnuala, Access is not a spreadsheet. Trying to use it as one will only result in more and more problems. I strongly suggest that you fully explain what you are trying to accomplish, so you can get some good advice.

Comment: is your "row number" a value of the primary key / index?

Comment: Thank you all for the replies! Actually I have a table(which I download from Excel workbook) and the number of the colmns changes all the time: the file is being updated and the number of columns increases each day (each column is actually a date and in the rows I have values for each day and in the last column the newest updated value). What I need is to create new table where I have just 2 columns: second column should be equal to the last column of previous file and the first column I want to put all other columns one under another. So for each old value i have right next the newest value.

Comment: Have a look at union queries to try and normalize your data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, but I solved my issue converting each row of my Table into Array

Comment: You should explain your solution to the problem in your answer. Use [edit] to add it.